# Get duplicate attributes in xml using schematron

Tags: duplicates, schematron

I am writing few checks for XML file using schematron.

I want to write down a check so that there must be no duplicate attribute `'id'` in any tag across the xml.
Please note, attribute `'id'` can occur in any element across the xml.
I found something related to this but that was case for siblings only which used preceding-sibling function.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I use. It's horribly inefficient to execute an XPath statement across the entire document for every element that might have an id attribute. So, I use an xsl:key. The solution below uses ISO Schematron.

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    queryBinding="xslt2" schemaVersion="ISO19757-3">

    <xsl:key name="xmlid" match="*[@id]" use="@id"/>

    <pattern id="duplicate_id"> 
        <rule context="*[@id]"> 
           <assert test="count(key('xmlid', @id)) = 1">
           Duplicated id in element "<name/>" - "<value-of select='@id'/>".
           </assert>
        </rule> 
    </pattern> 
</schema>
```

The key caches all the elements that have an `id` attribute. The rule then applies to all elements with that attribute. The assertion simply counts the number of matches against the `id` attribute and produces an error message if the count isn't one.